# System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' visual studio

Tags: java, visual-studio-2010

I was writing code and it worked I closed the file and reopened it later and it started throwing errors at the foreach loop. any help is much appreciated. don't know if I'm blind and just cant see what I may have changed in reopening it.

```
        StreamReader inputFile;
        string line; 
        int count = 0;
        int total;


        char[] delim = { ',' }; 

        inputFile = File.OpenText("Numbers.txt");


        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {

            count++;


            line = inputFile.ReadLine();

            // get the test scores as tokens
            string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);


            // set accumulator to 0
            total = 0;

            foreach (string str in tokens)
            {
                total += int.Parse(str);
            }


            TotalLable.Text = total.ToString("N");
        }
        inputFile.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

int.Parse(str), can you print you str. It seems the string cannot be parsed to a number. Paste the contents of Numbers.txt. Check if any whitespace or any other special char is there..